# How to add values in multidimensional object with polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm new with polymer and I'm having serious problems with this tool, the most recent trying to add elements in a multidimensional object.

I have declared an object as follows:

```
tabArrayTest: {
      type: Object,
      value: [{
                tabName:"visita1",
                inputs: [{value:"", placeholder:"t1_input1"}]

              },
              {
                tabName:"visita2",
                inputs: [{value:"", placeholder:"t2_input1"}]
              },
              {
                tabName:"visita3",
                inputs: [{value:"", placeholder:"t3_input1"}]
              },
                  {
                tabName:"visita4",
                inputs: [{value:"", placeholder:"t4_input1"}]
              }]
    }
```

I want to implement a function that allows me to add new elements in the input of the selected object. Resulting something like this:

```
tabArrayTest: {
      type: Object,
      value: [{
                tabName:"visita1",
                inputs: [{value:"", placeholder:"t1_input1"},{value:"", placeholder:"t1_input2"},{value:"", placeholder:"t1_input3"}]

              },
              {
                tabName:"visita2",
                inputs: [{value:"", placeholder:"t2_input1"}]
              },
              {
                tabName:"visita3",
                inputs: [{value:"", placeholder:"t3_input1"}]
              },
                  {
                tabName:"visita4",
                inputs: [{value:"", placeholder:"t4_input1"}]
              }]
    }
```

Is this possible ?, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of polymer's [array mutation methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#array-mutation)

For example:

```
pushInputToTab: function (tabIndex, newInput) {
    this.push('tabArrayTest.' + tabIndex + '.inputs', newInput);
}
```